# Facebook API V2.0 Extended Permissions for Development and Testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm in the early stages of building a complex application that will tie into Facebook to customize a story using a Facebook user's personal information. I've successfully been able to request basic permissions, grab their name, and include it in the story.

I'm at the point now where I'd like to include some of the user's photos as well, but I'm running into problems with permissions. When I try to get an access_token using user_photos, I'm told that:

*"The following permissions have not been approved for use and will not be shown to people using [APPNAME]: user_photos. Submit them for review or learn more."*

If I have a look at my Facebook app settings page, I'm told the approval process can take up to 7 days and requires screenshots, and instructions how a reviewer can test my implementation of the desired permissions.

I don't understand how this is supposed to work. It seems like a chicken and egg situation. How can I build my application if I don't have permission to access any photos through the API? How can they test and determine if they want to give me permissions if I can't build the app they need to test?

Is there some testing or development mode I'm missing? Is there a test user I can use? I've tried creating a testing/development version of the application and granting permissions with an admin user, and still no dice.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is just a warning. You can always ask any user that have a role on the app for any permission.

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice if I click "Edit Permissions" on the request dialog, photos is in the list. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just a warning. You can always ask any user that have a role on the app for any permission