# Can not get photos from facebook test users profile with user_photos permission

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an app that uses user's facebook photos. To get user's profile photos from facebook i use user_photos permission. It worked great for me. When i logged in as a test user app correctly grabbed my photos. So i submitted my app to facebook review and review didn't approve user_photos permission. And after this moment i cann't receive any photos even from app's test users.

Can anyone help me with this situation?
Many thanks!

Comment: See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045624/facebook-api-v2-0-extended-permissions-for-development-and-testing